# AdoDB function doesn't work with utf8 cast in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation, adodb

We have a query that is like this:

```
select C.* from stream_data AS sd 
JOIN Conversations AS C 
ON (C.conversationReferenceId = sd.stream_data_id AND smAccountId = ?) 
WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1
```

and we run it using AdoDB. like this:

```
$object = new Conversation();
$object->LoadFromRawQuery("select C.* from stream_data AS sd JOIN Conversations AS C ON (C.conversationReferenceId = sd.stream_data_id AND smAccountId = ?) WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1", array($socialmediaAccountId, $parentSourceId));
```

(Note: We have a custom version of AdoDB that has a method called LoadFromRawQuery in AdoDB_RecordSet class, but the problem can be seen using a standard Execute() method call, so I am letting it be.)

To improve the performance of this query (based on our indices), we added a cast operator:

```
#Query:
select C.* from stream_data AS sd 
JOIN Conversations AS C 
ON (C.conversationReferenceId = cast(sd.stream_data_id as char) collate utf8_unicode_ci AND smAccountId = ?) 
WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1

#PHP
$object = new Conversation();
$object->LoadFromRawQuery("select C.* from stream_data AS sd JOIN Conversations AS C ON (C.conversationReferenceId = cast(sd.stream_data_id as char) collate utf8_unicode_ci AND smAccountId = ?) WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1", array($socialmediaAccountId, $parentSourceId));
```

Both operations work in Console, but in AdoDB, the first operation succeeds, while the second operation fails. All our tables are on UTF8 Charset.

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that - by default ADODB doesn't know the charset of the DB. So, it asks MySQL to provide the same through a query like:

```
mysql> SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
    -> WHERE schema_name = "xxxxxx";
+----------------------------+
| default_character_set_name |
+----------------------------+
| latin1                     |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This would return latin1, since the default charset in mysql in Latin1 is latin1. You can fix it at create database time by adding charset (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html), Since MySQL's DB is on latin1, but the tables are in utf8, MySQL diligently returns latin1. Now, AdoDB sets the connection to latin1.

When this mixes with your collation "utf8_unicode_ci", MySQL returns an error:

```
ErrorMsg: COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

Now, you have two options. When setting up the DB Connection, call the following to force the connection to be set to ut8 charset:

```
$object->DB()->SetCharSet('utf8');
// Or
$connection->SetCharSet('utf8');
```

**Recommendation:**

Alternatively, instead of casting the element to a string, you just concatenate '' with the number and at this point MySQL will cast it for you and do so with the right collation and hence you won't have the error - and I checked using EXPLAIN - both the cast and concatenate version used the same indexing and ordering structure:

```
#Query:
select C.* from stream_data AS sd 
JOIN Conversations AS C 
ON (C.conversationReferenceId = CONCAT('', sd.stream_data_id) AND smAccountId = ?) 
WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1

#PHP
$object = new Conversation();
$object->LoadFromRawQuery("select C.* from stream_data AS sd JOIN Conversations AS C ON (C.conversationReferenceId = CONCAT('', sd.stream_data_id) AND smAccountId = ?) WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1", array($socialmediaAccountId, $parentSourceId));

echo("\r\n"."SQL : ".'select C.* from stream_data AS sd JOIN Conversations AS C ON (C.conversationReferenceId = CONCAT(\'\', sd.stream_data_id) AND smAccountId = ?) WHERE sd.stream_id = ? LIMIT 1'."\r\n");
echo("\r\n".'RESULT OBJECT AFTER DOING THE CONCAT : '."\r\n".json_encode($parentConversation)."\r\n");
```